# Storing Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY in MySQL (EJB entity/JBoss)

Tags: mysql, jpa, jboss, ejb, infinity

I have the following simple JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = myentity_table )
public class MyEntity {

  private double a;
  private double b;
  //(...)
}
```

**a** and **b** may be set to `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. When I try to store entity with double set to +INF into database (MySQL) using standard entity manager I get exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: 'Infinity' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value

As far as I know MySQL may not support NaN/-INF/+INF numbers. Is there any way to store this entity without writing HQL queries and translating +INF into null (or max double) ? Ideally,  I'd like to do it via entity manager as usual.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity life-cycle callback methods @PrePersist, @PreUpdate can be used here to verify the field value NAN/-INF/+INF etc & then setting the default value accordingly.

```
 //--

 @PrePersist  
 @PreUpdate  
 private void resetField() {

      if(field == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
            field = somePredefinedValue;
 }

 //--
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! My solution is to use pre/post callbacks and (as I've chosen) in case of +INF set field to Double.MAX_VALUE (it's for pre* callbacks, for post it should be done MAX->+INF)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't seem to support "infinity". [This article](http://www.ryannitz.org/tech-notes/2009/01/19/mysql-and-negative-infinity/) writes that:

> Storing and retrieving negative infinity in a MySQL database is accomplished by inserting an arbitrarily large negative number.

Same goes for positive. [Other resources](http://lists.mysql.com/java/5996) also use `1e500`.

Instead of using infinity, I would suggest that you use `Float.MAX_VALUE` and `Float.MIN_VALUE` (or `Double` equivalents)

If you can't do this in your code when setting the values, do it in a `@PrePersist` as already suggested.

Comment: I like the idea of intentionally using non-infinite constants to effectively represent infinity in the application. The `@PrePersist` method may surprise users of your code if they tried to store infinity but get something else back.

For my application, I chose 1e12 (1 trillion) as the value representing infinity since we don't have a requirement to store a value above that. I liked a nice, round number like 1 trillion better than Float.MAX_VALUE because it's much easier to write in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this problem by adding a varchar column to store the text representation of `Float.NaN`, `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` while the original column will store `NULL`. 
Then I use the setter and the getter to do manage those two columns.

In my @Entity class

```
/** The value I persist. See it is a Float; */
@Column(name = "VALUE")
private Float value;

/** the 'value complement' that does the trick. */
@Column(name = "VALUE_COMPLEMENT") // You can see I've added a new column in my table (it is a varchar)
private String valueComplement;

/**
 * value getter.
 * If my value is null, it could mean that it is a NaN or +/- infinity.
 * Then let's check the complement.
 */
public Float getValue() {
    if (value == null) {
        try {
            return Float.parseFloat(this.valueComplement);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

/**
 * value setter
 * If the given value is a NaN or Inf, set this.value to null 
 * and this.complement to the string representation of NaN or +/- Inf.
 */
public void setValue(Float value) {
    if (value != null && (value.isNaN() || value.isInfinite())) {
        this.valueComplement = value.toString();
        this.value = null;
    } else {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Result :

```
| ID | LABEL                 | VALUE | VALUE_COMPLEMENT |
| -- | --------------------- | ----- | ---------------- |
|  1 | PI                    |  3.14 | NULL             |
|  2 | gravity acceleration  |  9.81 | NULL             |
|  3 | sqare root of -1      | NULL  | NaN              |
|  4 | log of 0              | NULL  | -Infinity        |
```